# How can new members create a password?

Tags: wordpress

How can I enable new users who register on my Wordpress/CiviCRM site to create a password (for a member login)?

Comment: How are they registering? Is it a 'civicrm profile? is the profile set to 'create CMS user'?

Answer (score 0):

As Pete suggests, check the following if a profile is in use:

For the Civi profile under 'Advanced settings' tick either:

WordPress user account registration option?

- Give option, but not required
- Account creation required

In Wordpress under 'Settings' - 'General' you have to ensure that ' Anyone can register' is also enabled.

Once that's done you should be able to preview/test the sign up form (thought the create account options only show if not already logged in or using a private browsing window).